# what happened if an exception is not captured?

Tags: c++, exception

I am not asking an unexpected exception, but an exception that is not captured.

Crashed? Or terminated?

Answer (score 7):

According to §15.3/9:

> **If no matching handler is found in a program, the function terminate() is called**; whether or not the stack is unwound before this call to terminate() is implementation-defined (15.5.1). <sub>Emphasis mine</sub>

What happens after that is up to your OS. In practice: a crash. (Or if you're in a debugger, "Hey, you didn't catch this.")

Answer (score 0):

Typically terminate will call abort() which quits the process, possibly dumping a core, or if a debugger is attached, stops in the debugger so you can see what happened. If you don't catch the exception somewhere, the program cannot continue.